# Swift 4 Textview goes to bottom of textview when press return key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, textview

When I press return button when editing my textview, it makes a new line where I currently am editing the textview and it automatically goes to the bottom of the textview text. I think it is because I am using Firebase to keep the textview in realtime text so it can update on all devices. When i remove the observer in the following code, it works like its supposed to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    textView.delegate = self




    ref.child("Notes").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let note = snapshot.value as? [String : String]

        self.textView.text = note!["note"]

    })
}
```

I also have this code to update the database with the text in the texview:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { //Fires when the textview text changes
    print(textView.text)
    self.ref.child("Notes/note").setValue(textView.text)

}
```

I think i am having a problem because it gets the text from the database and sets a new copy of the text into the textview how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you really want to update Firebase for every character typed into the text view? Why not wait until the text view loses focus?

Comment: I am trying to make a realtime notes app so it would great if i can figure this out by sending each character to the database so that different users can edit the same document

Comment: Maybe you should avoid setting the text view's `text` property if the value of `note["note"]` is the same as the current value.